# Finite quotient ring over prime ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $d$ be a square free integer. Let $R=\{a+b\sqrt{d}:a,b\in\mathbb{Z}\}$.
Also $P\subset R$ is a prime ideal. I want to show that the factor ring $R/P$ is finite. (No group theory only ring theory)

I know that if $I$ is a nonzero ideal, the $I\cap\mathbb{Z}$ is a nonzero ideal in $Z$. Also $I\cap\mathbb{Z}=(n)$ for some positive integer $n$. Also I know $R/P$ has no zero divisors.

So I looked at some other post and I still don't understand the connection between $R/(n)$ (which is a finite set), $(R/(n))/P$ (how does this look like), and $R/P$.

Comment: duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2559019/276986

Comment: If $n \in P$ then $P = (P,n)$ and $R/P = S/\tilde{P}$ where $S = R/(n)$ and $\tilde{P}$ means "$P / (n)$" ie. $\{ a+n R, a \in P\}$ a set of subsets of $R$ and an ideal of $R/(n)$. Example : $\mathbb{Z}/(2) = (\mathbb{Z}/(4))/(2)$.

Comment: @reuns Ok for example if I had $R/(3)$. So $8\equiv 2\pmod{3}$ and $4\equiv 1\pmod{3}$ then $8+4\sqrt{d}\equiv 2+\sqrt{d}\pmod{3}$. This means that $R/(3)$ is finite since $a$ and $b$ will be modded by $3$.

Comment: Yes. Try with $R = \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}], P = (\sqrt{3})$. What do you get for $R/P$ ?

Comment: @reuns how does $(\sqrt{3})$ look like? Is it of the form $(a+b\sqrt{3})\cdot (\sqrt{3})=a\sqrt{3}+b3$?

Comment: $(\sqrt{3})$ is the principal ideal of $R$ generated by $\sqrt{3})$, thus $(\sqrt{3}) = \{ \alpha \sqrt{3}, \alpha \in R\} = \{ a\sqrt{3}+3b, (a,b) \in \mathbb{Z}^2\}$. After try again with $R = \mathbb{Z}[i], P = (2+i)$.

Comment: @reuns ok I know $(\sqrt{3})$ contains $3$. Does that mean we can mod $a$ and $b$ by $3$? So $3\in P\cap\mathbb{Z}$. For $(2+i)$ contains $5$. So similarly we can mod $a$ and $b$ by $5$. So $5\in P\cap\mathbb{Z}$ Why?

Comment: You should go back to the basics, ie. quotienting by one element, try to make sense to it, then compare with the definition of $R/P$ as a ring whose elements are subsets of $R$ of the form $a+P, a \in R$.